# Xamarin Forms - Autofill password is not working for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, autofill

I want to implement Password autofill functionality for my Xamarin app, i followed the steps on https://mikalaidaronin.info/blog/posts/xamarin-forms-password-autofill and it is working fine for Android, but it is not working for iOS, i do not see password save popup for my iOS app.

Is there any additional step needed apart from the mentioned on the blog above?

Comment: Are you using a Simulator ? N.B. It is preferable to use a physical iOS device to test it out. If you are on a simulator, go to settings of the simulator → Passwords → turn on AutoFill Passwords.

Comment: @BasH i am using simulator and yes i enabled the AutoFill Passwords in simulator

Comment: When you try the Github does it work https://github.com/lassana/XamarinFormsPasswordAutofill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it, for me the issue was that Entitlements.plist was not selected as "Custom Entitlements" in project settings.

1. Double click on the iOS Project or right click on iOS project and click on options
2. Select "iOS Bundle Signing" from the Left Side
   [image]
3. Click on the 3 dots for the "Custom Entitlements" and select your Entitlement.plist file.
   [image]
4. Rebuild the project.